# Twilio sms line break doesn't work

Tags: sms, twilio

I'm a Twilio user and i tried to do a line break (with \n command) on the sms body form on the API explorer page but it doesn't work.

Here you can find a screenshot :

[image]

Thank you very much

Comment: Please do not link to external resources! Provide everything needed in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following code via PHP script and works fine, without escaping the new line.

```
  <?php
      require('/Users/user/Documents/Twilio/Development/PHP/libraries/twilio-php-master/Services/Twilio.php'); // This line loads the helper library

      $sid = "XXXXXXXXX"; // Your Account SID from www.twilio.com/user/account
      $token = "YYYYYYYY"; // Your Auth Token from www.twilio.com/user/account

      $client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token); // instance of the Twilio helper REST Client

      $from = "+1 415-319-1111"; // a valid Twilio number
      $to =  "+1408-319-2222"; // your mobile number
      $body = "Ahoy from Twilio!\n New line"; // sms message body

      try {
        $message = $client->account->messages->sendMessage( $from, $to, $body);
        echo $message->sid; // Twilio's identifier for the new message
      } catch (Services_Twilio_RestException $e) {
          echo $e->getMessage(); // A message describing the REST error
      }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

This is probably a case of the API explorer escaping things for you. I just tried using the Ruby helper library and got an SMS message with a line break in it. Have you tried using the API itself?